# Where is this Rashba on prayer?

Tags: tefilla, tractate-brachot, rashba

I remember I read that the Rashba has a beautiful piece of advice for Tefilla (prayer):

To always remember what he have is due to HaShem’s kindness, to always remember that HaShem is capable of answering all our Tefillot, and to always remember that “Ein Od Milvado” - only HaShem can answer us, no one else.

I vaguely remember this Rashba being quoted from his commentary on the Gemara in Brachos. Does anyone know?

Comment: Maybe Berachos 12?